# Creating Calendar Event - Custom Times - Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api, google-forms

I want a calendar event to be created on submission of a form. Users are entering a date from which I would like to use Google Apps Script to create an event in a specific calendar that starts at 9am and finishes at 5pm.

I know I could ask the users to manually enter the start and finish times but I'd rather use GAS to automatically do it based on the date field.

This is what I have currently:

```
   var vSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var vS = vSS.getSheetByName("blah blah blah");
   var vLastRow = vS.getLastRow();
   var vStartDate = vS.getRange(vLastRow,6);
   var vStartDateValue = vStartDate.getValues();
   var vEndDate = vS.getRange(vLastRow,7);
   var vEndDateValue = vEndDate.getValues();
```

What do I need to do to get this to work?

Comment: You've got `createEvent()` in code in some of your previous questions, so you probably know about that function. Can you be more specific about what your problem is? And explain why you have two dates, because that doesn't jive with the question? (PS: to get the value of a single cell, use `getValue()`, not `getValues()`.)

Comment: The Start Date and End Date can be different, possibly 2-3 days out. I'm currently using this to create the event but the value of vStartValue and vEndValue don't have times associated to them so it doesn't create the event correctly.       calendar.createEvent('Booked',new Date (vStartDateValue),new Date (vEndDateValue), {location:Office});

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this [function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createEvent(String,Date,Date,Object)) to create an event with start date and end date.

For adding the startTime and endTime, just append the time value(09 AM or 05 PM) to the "vStartDateValue".

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this by using the following code:

```
 function CreateEvent(){
 var vSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var vS = vSS.getSheetByName("blah blah blah");
 var vLastRow = vS.getLastRow();
 var vCalendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarbyID('xxxxxx@joent.com')
 var vStartDate = vS.getRange(vLastRow,6);
 var vStartDateValue = new Date (vStartDate.getValue());
      vStartDateValue.setHours(9);
 var vEndDate = vS.getRange(vLastRow,7);
 var vEndDateValue = new Date (vEndDate.getValue());
      vEndDateValue.setHours(17);

 vCalendar.createEvent('Description',
                        vStartDateValue,
                        vEndDateValue)
  }
```